# Menu items not Appearing

Tags: android

I am trying to implement a tab style menu bar in my Android app, however any `<item />` I add to the menu is not displaying in the Preview (see image below).

Preview of menu/menu_navigation.xml:

(The `<item />` included in menu/menu_navigation.xml is not being displayed)

[image: item not displayed in Android Preview]

menu/menu_navigation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
>

<item
    android:id="@+id/bMenu"
    android:title="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    />
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:design="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context="com.engineeringeric.parkerapp.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    design:menu="@menu/menu_navigation">
</android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>
```

Comment: Please, post your code for us to analyze. Thank you.

Comment: Hello, there is no Java code written for the described UI elements as I do not believe Java is required just for designing/displaying a tabs UI. All xml that I am using is provided above. Thanks.

Comment: On your preview window, the simulated mobile phone, why it is selected "No Action Bar?". Maybe this... cause it's forcing to use a style with no bar... and you want to show tabs that's living in tab bar...

Comment: What value should this field have? When I try to switch it to "AppTheme" Android Studio changes it to "NoActionBar"

Comment: Yeah, i think the value would have to be AppTheme or whatever different from NoActionBar. My fear is: maybe your menu is not appearing only on your preview window, not in a real situation, i.e., on your mobile or emulator maybe your menu is showed. Are you able to run your app? Running, menu doesn't show either?

Comment: You are correct, the tab navigation displays correctly in the emulator. I hadn't tried debugging it since adding the menu_navigation.xml file to the app. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your preview window, the simulated mobile phone, change "No Action Bar" for whatever you can, because this is instructing the preview window to hide your menu.

Probably your menu is not appearing only on your preview window, not in a real situation, i.e., on your mobile or emulator maybe your menu is showed.

Put your app to run at your mobile or emulator and see if I'm correct.